# Cannot Resolve Symbol 'setOnClickListener'

Tags: java, android

I am fairly new to Android/Java developing and I have run into this error. I cannot figure out what is wrong after doing extensive research and playing with my methods. Here is my code:

```
package org.flinthill.finalprojectv2;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.text.method.DigitsKeyListener;
import android.text.InputFilter;

public class mainactivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    final Button SuSe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SuSe);
    SuSe.setOnClickListener()

    {
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){

            }
        };
    }
}
```

If anyone knows what I could've done wrong, please let me know! Thanks!

Comment: does anyone know what this error is? http://imgur.com/a/Hxz5O

Answer (score 1):

Put the code inSide `onCreate()`

```
 public class mainactivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Button SuSe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SuSe);
        SuSe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Button Clicked 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @KamehK Welcome to Stack overflow.if the answer helps ..mark it as correct by clicking the Tick sign next to the answer..Thankx

Answer (score 1):

put your code inside **onCreate()** method

**see the android lifeCycle to understand why** :https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 0):

Your code is out of your method, Change it to this:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Button SuSe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SuSe);
        SuSe.setOnClickListener()

        {
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){

            }
        };
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do `Button` initialization and adding `listener` to `Button` inside `onCreate()` method.

**Try this:**

```
package org.flinthill.finalprojectv2;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.text.method.DigitsKeyListener;
import android.text.InputFilter;

public class mainactivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button SuSe;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SuSe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SuSe);

        SuSe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Do something
            }
        });
    }   
}
```